# Arguments of complex numbers identity

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have been solving a STEP question and I have come across a new concept, which is an argument of a complex number.

Basically, to solve a problem, I had to consider the following: $(5-i)^2 (1+i)$, the solver proceeded:$Z_1 = (5-i)^2 (1+i)$, $Z_2 = (5-i)$ and $Z_3=(1+i)$. My question is, where does the following identity come from: $arg(Z_1)=2 arg(Z_2)+arg(Z_3)$ and how did the solver know which $Z$'s to pick, why $Z_2$ is $(5-i)$ and not $(5-i)^2$, say?

EDIT:

The part of the question that I was considering is the following:

"By considering $(5-i)^2(1+i)$, show that $\arctan{\frac{7}{17}}+2 \arctan{\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{\pi}{4}$"

Comment: There are two things that I would like to say to you: -First please state the question, second the Argument of a complex number is the angle which the ray joining the origin and the complex number, make with the positive x-axis. To understand the reason why the complex number follows the property you have mentioned above, you could consider converting the complex number into polar form Re^i(theta) where theta is the argument. If two numbers of the above form are multiplied then the angles in the exponent will add up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$(5-i)^2(1+i)=34+14i$$
$$\Rightarrow \arg (5-i)^2(1+i)=\arg (34+14i)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\arg (5-i)+\arg (1+i)=\arg(34+14i)$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Are these the properties of $\arg$ then? : $\arg{A}^n=n\arg{A}$ and $\arg{AB}=\arg{A}+\arg{B}$

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

I resolve your question otherwise without the use of complex numbers.
In the equality to be proved $\arctan {\frac{7}{17}}+2 \arctan{\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{\pi}{4}$, calculate first the arc corresponding to $2 \arctan{\frac{1}{5}}$

[image]

One has in the figure $AB=\sqrt{5^2+(1+x)^2}=\sqrt {x^2+2x+26}$ hence, by the bisectrix theorem, the equation giving $x$

$$\frac {5}{1}= \frac {\sqrt {x^2+2x+26}}{x}\Rightarrow x=\frac{13}{12}$$
Therefore $$2 \arctan {\frac{1}{5}}=\arctan{\frac{1+\frac{13}{12}}{5}}=\arctan{\frac{5}{12}}$$
Now $$\arctan {\frac{7}{17}}+2 \arctan{\frac{1}{5}} = \arctan {\frac{7}{17}}+ \arctan{\frac{5}{12}}$$ and we take the tangents; 
we get

$$\tan(\arctan{\frac{7}{17}}+ \arctan{\frac{5}{12}})=\frac{7/17+5/12}{1-35/(17*12)}=\frac{169}{169}=1$$
This is well the tangent of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is equal to $1$